# How to find (mobility*Cox) and Vth

Tags: mosfet, cmos, modeling, cadence, virtuoso

How to find "mobility*Cox" and "threshold voltage" of NMOS in cadence virtuoso?

I have performed DC analysis in schematic environment and using NMOS model parameters, I tried to find mobility, Cox and threshold voltage. But I could not find them. Can you help me? Should I use fundamental formula, for example, for Cox, should I use epsilon/Tox?

Comment: I would expect Vth to be one of the op point annotations (open schematic from ADE, right click empty space, annotate, DC operating points, right click again, setup, pick your nmos cell, add the vth op point parameter to the list), while the oxide/channel is modeled with much more than just mobility\*c_ox on a BSIM or EKV model. Can you elaborate on why you're looking for these values (so we know what estimations you want to make), and what you *were* able to find from your PDK's models?

Comment: Hello @nanofarad, thank you. it is just an exercise.